# Change object value outside of dataframe Python

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote a simple oop code with Python, and I used pandas.
I have two classes, In first class I created a object, and in the second class I put that object in dataframe. I have a function `set_name(self, name)` that changes the name of the object.

My question is, why does object name stay the same inside of dataframe (when I print the dataframe) and changes when I just want to print object?
If I change the object name, It should change everywhere, it does not matter where I put that object, right?

Is there a way to fix this?

```
import pandas as pd


class A:
    def __init__(self, name , age):

        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def set_name(self, new_name):
        self.name = new_name
        return "Name changed to " + self.name

    def __repr__(self):

        info = "My name is: " + self.name + " Im " + str(self.age) + " yo"
        return info


obj_1 = A("Mike",22)

first_list = [obj_1]
print(first_list)

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj_list_one = [obj_1]
        self.obj_list_two = pd.DataFrame(
            [[obj_1.name, obj_1.age]],
            columns=["Name", "age"])

my_object = B()


#print(my_object.obj_list_one)
print(my_object.obj_list_two)

print(obj_1.set_name("Steve"))

#print(first_list)

#print(my_object.obj_list_one)
print(my_object.obj_list_two)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But when you do:

```
self.obj_list_two = pd.DataFrame(
            [[obj_1.name, obj_1.age]],
            columns=["Name", "age"])
```

`obj_1.name`'s string value is copied to the data frame, not the object itself. That's why it stays `Mike` while `self.obj_list_one.name` changes to `Steve.

Comment: Ok, Is there a way to fix this? Can i insert object inside dataframe so that It changes when I change the object?

Comment: If you have only one object, you already did so with `self.obj_list_one`. Or `pd.Series` of objects if you have many?

Comment: I have a lot of objects, I just gave example with one.
Can you please give me an example code?

Comment: `self.obj_list_two = pd.Series([obj1, obj2,...])`. Also, I'm not sure why you need to use pandas, `self.obj_list_two = [ojb1, obj2,...]` seems good enough.

Comment: Sorry, I have tried your solution, but It does not work. I want to have dataframe with columns and values (like I have in dataframe that i posted in my code).  I use pandas jut for representation of objects.